# Showing arbitrary @Timed metrics in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I am trying to add time metrics to my spring-boot web application. Right now, the application uses micrometer, prometheus, and spring-boot-actuator.

I can connect to my app at http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus and see the list of default metrics like:

```
# HELP jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total Incremented for an increase in the size of the young generation memory pool after one GC to before the next
# TYPE jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total counter
jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total{application="my app",} 0.0
# HELP jvm_classes_loaded_classes The number of classes that are currently loaded in the Java virtual machine
# TYPE jvm_classes_loaded_classes gauge
jvm_classes_loaded_classes{application="my app",} 7581.0
...
```

Awesome!

But now I'd like to attach timing metrics to the methods of one of my controllers. I'd hoped it was as simple as adding an `@Timed` annotation to the class:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;

@RestController
@Timed
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        doWork();
        return buildResponse(name);
    }

    private void doWork() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (1000 * Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    private Greeting buildResponse(String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't appear to add any metrics to the http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus endpoint.

What steps do I need to take in order to have the endpoint report timing metrics of the `GreetingController` class, and particularly the `doWork` and `buildResponse` methods?

-- update --

I've managed to get the results I want but it took a little more work than I was expecting, and I'm hoping that there is an easier way. I explicitly added `Timer` objects to each method I wanted to measure like so:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @Autowired
    MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        doWork();
        return buildResponse(name);
    }

    private void doWork() {
        Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".doWork");
        timer.record(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (1000 * Math.random()));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        });
    }

    private Greeting buildResponse(String name) {
        AtomicReference<Greeting> response = new AtomicReference<>();

        Timer timer = meterRegistry.timer(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + ".buildResponse");
        timer.record(() -> {
            response.set(new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name)));
        });

        return response.get();
    }
}
```

But at least this gets me the results I was looking for:

```
# HELP GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds  
# TYPE GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds summary
GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds_count{application="my app",} 10.0
GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds_sum{application="my app",} 0.001531409
# HELP GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds_max  
# TYPE GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds_max gauge
GreetingController_buildResponse_seconds_max{application="my app",} 2.52253E-4
# HELP GreetingController_doWork_seconds_max  
# TYPE GreetingController_doWork_seconds_max gauge
GreetingController_doWork_seconds_max{application="my app",} 0.941169892
# HELP GreetingController_doWork_seconds  
# TYPE GreetingController_doWork_seconds summary
GreetingController_doWork_seconds_count{application="my app",} 10.0
GreetingController_doWork_seconds_sum{application="my app",} 4.767700907
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3):

Register [TimedAspect](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/latest/io/micrometer/core/aop/TimedAspect.html) as a bean in the configuration class:

```
@Bean
public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    return new TimedAspect(meterRegistry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case prometheusMeterRegistry were created to early and it was necessary to apply following hack

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "app.metrics.enabled", matchIfMissing = true, havingValue = "true")
static class AppMetricsConfig {

    @Bean
    InitializingBean forcePrometheusPostProcessor(BeanPostProcessor meterRegistryPostProcessor,
                                                  PrometheusMeterRegistry registry) {
      return () -> meterRegistryPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(registry, "");
    }

    /**
     * This is required so that we can use the @Timed annotation
     * on methods that we want to time.
     * See: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_the_timed_annotation
     */
    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(HikariDataSource dataSource, MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new TimedAspect(registry);
    }
}
```

see more details https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/513

Answer (score -1):

@Timed("Greeting")
must append tag